# Upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10, now alt+tab doesn't work anymore

Tags: upgrade, 18.10

I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 using the standard procedure, and now alt+tab for switching between applications doesn't work anymore.

Any idea on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I found myself, it was caused by "AlternateTab" gnome extension... There was an update for it too...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue after upgrade to 18.10 and [upgraded](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) the "AlternateTab" Gnome extension, as well

Afterwards, I encountered an issue where a red "Error" box appeared next to the extension and it still was not working post upgrade
To resolve, I had to restart my machine